# How do I throw an HttpParseException from my custom server control when a required property is missing?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, custom-server-controls

My server control requires some properties to be set through markup like this:

```
<cc:MyControl runat="server" Property="Required" />
```

When a developer forgets to add the property, I throw an exception. This happens in the getter for the public property:

```
public string Property
{
  get { return GetRequiredPropertyFromViewState["Property"]; }
  set { ViewState["Property"] = value; }
}
```

In the YSOD I get a source error and stack trace. The source that is displayed is that of my custom control class:

> ```
> Line 173:   throw new ArgumentException(message);
> ```

I'd like to display the markup of the control as the source error. Is that possible?

I only know that the WebForms page parser will sometimes show parse errors with markup in the source error. <del>But these are not actually exceptions.</del>

Edit: I was wrong. Parse errors can be thrown, using [HttpParseException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpparseexception.aspx). But you have specify file, source code and line number. I don't know if I can provide those from within my custom control. I need these three, of which I don't know how to get the last two:

1. virtualPath: I can get from Page.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath
2. source:
3. line:

Answer (score 0):

I found that you cannot do this from the control itself, because once it gets  initialized it cannot get back to the parser infrastructure.

But you can associate a [control builder class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.controlbuilder.aspx) with your server control. This class participates in the parsing of the page. If you throw an `HttpParserException` with just an error message from the Init method, then the code and the line of the control markup is added by the framework.

I came up with this method to validate required properties based on data annotations:

```
private void ValidateAttribute(PropertyInfo attribute, object value)
{
  // Reflect all the data annotations' validator attributes on the control property...
  object[] validators = attribute.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ValidationAttribute), false);

  // ...and validate each one
  foreach (ValidationAttribute validator in validators)
  {
    try
    {
      validator.Validate(value, attribute.Name);
    }
    catch (ValidationException exception)
    {
      // Show as parser error in browser
      throw new HttpParseException(exception.Message);
    }
  }
}
```

Call it from [`ControlBuilder.Init()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.controlbuilder.init.aspx) and associate the control builder with a server control using the [`ControlBuilderAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.controlbuilderattribute.aspx).